# Ubuntu terminal file explorer/commander

Tags: command-line

What is the terminal application in this screenshot and how can I install and start it?

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "call out"?

Comment: to open this from terminal

Comment: Closely related: “[Is there a file explorer/manager for the command line?](/q/222345/175814)” especially the [accepted answer](/a/222349/175814).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The screenshot you show looks like [Midnight Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midnight_Commander).

Install it using the command:

```
sudo apt install mc
```

Then you can open it in your terminal by typing

```
mc
```